# I'm using AppAuth iOS for login purpose in app. I receives authState nil and error saying "Invalid Client"

Tags: ios, authorization, okta, appauth, gluu

Process:
User Opens the app.
Taps on login.
Redirected to login page.
User enter credentials.
Redirected back to app.
Received authState **nil** and error "Invalid Client".

```
let authorizationEndpoint = URL(string: ConfigRouter.AuthorizationEndpoint)!
    let tokenEndpoint = URL(string: ConfigRouter.TokenEndpoint)!
    let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint,
                                                tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint)
    var parameters = ConfigRouter.AdditionalParameters
    
    let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration,
                                              clientId: ClientId,
                                              clientSecret: ConfigRouter.OktaClientSecret,
                                              scopes: Scope,
                                              redirectURL:  URL(string: RedirectURL)!,
                                              responseType: ResponseType,
                                              additionalParameters: parameters)
    }
  

    self.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()!, prefersEphemeralSession: true, callback: { authState, error in
        if let authState = authState {
            let response = AuthHelper.shared.createResponse(authState: authState)
            AuthHelper.shared.saveAuthState(state: authState)
            completionHandler(.success(response))
        } else {
            if error != nil {
                completionHandler(.failure(error!))
            }
        }
        
    })
```

Identity Provider is GlUU. In Android is working fine with same configuration.

Comment: Is there any other way I will receive auth code and based on that will exchange required token?

Comment: Sure you are using correct client Id? And you do not have different client Id's for iOS and Android?

Comment: Yeah I'm using same for android and iOS.  I got the auth code from authorization request now but while making token request I'm receiving invalid client request.
Checking that now.

Comment: No my point was client Id's are usually different per client. So Android and iOS should be using different client Id's.

Comment: I've added what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**OIDAuthState.authState()** attempts to perform certain operations on our behalf. For example, showing AuthorizationRequest, getting authentication code from server, and from that authentication code requesting token. As a result, authState will directly return tokens such as access tokens, ID tokens, and refresh tokens. It worked fine for OKTA, but not for GLUU.

There might be a difference in the process followed between OKTA and GLUU, or perhaps setting up clients in GLUU server requires manual token calls.

Below steps helped me resolve the issue:

1. Usig **OIDAuthorizationService.present()** method to show authorization requet

   OIDAuthorizationService.present(request, presenting: UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()! )
2. This method will return authResponse if correct credentials were given. authReponse will have **authCode** based on which we will make another call for user tokens.
3. **Token Call based on authCode:**

   var request = URLRequest(url: tokenEndpointURL)
   request.httpMethod = gluuhttpMethodTypeKey
   request.setValue(gluuhRequestContentType , forHTTPHeaderField: gluuhRequestContentTypeKey)

   ```
   var bodyParameters = [
       gluuRefreshTokenGrantTypeKey  : OIDGrantTypeAuthorizationCode,
       ConfigRouter.OktaResponseType : authorizationCode,
       gluuRedirectURIKey            : redirectURI,
       gluuclientIdKey               : clientId,
       gluuclientSecretKey           : clientSecret,
       gluucodeVerifierKey           : codeVerifier,
       oktaRefreshTokenScopesKey     : scope
   ]
   bodyParameters.merge(ConfigRouter.OktaAdditionalParameters) { (_, new) in new }

   let bodyString = bodyParameters
       .map { "\($0)=\($1)" }
       .joined(separator: "&")

   request.httpBody = bodyString.data(using: .utf8)

   print("request\(request)")

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
   ```

Thanks